# Using only existing objects for many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to build my first real django app (after completing the tutorials) and currently have a hard time figuring out, how the model should look for my requirements.

Basically, i want to design a multiple purpose cv-app, switching between different versions, maintaining all of them easy : I have a class 'Version' (CV for Company XYZ or CV for Engineers Application) that contains mutliple 'Groupings' (like an 'Address' grouping or 'tech skills' grouping), which would contain key-value pairs for title and value. In the admin interface, i would like to maintain the groupings for each version via checkboxes (or something other) instead of relationship table because the groupings are shared between all versions. Each new Grouping would be automatically associated to all existing versions, defaulting for each of them with a 'disabled' property. Also, a newly created version would automatically list all existing groupings where i could check for each grouping, whether it would be used in the new version.

What i would like to avoid with this structure is to have Groupings, that have basically the same content (in one version a grouping like 'hobbies' and in another version a grouping 'interests'), providing the user/admin only a list of already existing groupings. If there would be the need to create a new grouping, you should create it separately.